# How to set subfolder in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, subdirectory

Im trying to set index.php file in my html folder as `localhost:5555` and my second index.php file in html/highlighter folder as `localhost:5555/highlighter` with first everything okay, but with second one not, when i go to `localhost:5555/highlighter` it prints `404 Not Found`
Can you help me?
My folders tree:

```
nginx
│ 
├── html
│   ├── 50x.html
│   ├── highlight
│   │   ├── functions.php
│   │   ├── icon.png
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.php
│   └── index.php
├── nginx.exe
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    server {
        listen       5555;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php;
        }
        
        location /highlighter {
            root html/highlight;
            index index.php;
        }
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
My mistake was adding 2 roots in location blocks, if you have same error, try move root from location block like this

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       5555;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   "D:\\Miscellaneous\\nginxSites";
        
        location / {
            index  index.php;
        }
        
        location /highlighter {
            index  index.php;
        }
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
location /highlighter {
            alias /var/www/html/highlighter/;
                index index.php index.html;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /highlighter/index.php;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried this, now instead of 404 error i got `No input file specified.`

Comment: I'm using Windows and my nginx folder located in root of C drive, if it might help you